# Map a Character key to some modifier key [say Control-key]?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, emacs, xkb

I am so used to emacs keybinding that I use emacs style keybindings on my entire system (with gtk settings). I've mapped <kbd>Caps-Lock</kbd> key to an extra <kbd>Control</kbd> key. But that doesn't help me from having pain after a few hour of work.

What I hope to do, is to map a character key (I'm looking at <kbd>l</kbd>) in a way that it functions normally on a Key_Press followed by a Key_Release, but acts as a <kbd>Control</kbd> key between the period of those two event - or effectively, when another key is pressed during that interval.

First off all, is this possible?
If yes, how would you do that?
Second, do you have any other suggestions on getting some work off the left pinky?

Comment: RSI (Repetitive strain injury) can become a life-changing problem: don't let it get to a stage where it is beyond repair. There is lots of software available to force you to take short breaks every so often. There are special keyboards. There are stretching exercises. These are better and simpler solutions that will ensure you continue working pain free the rest of your life.

Comment: I've always dreaded that. Thanks for wise words. I'll be sure to look into them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a project for X on Linux-based systems that does what you are asking, called `at-home-modifier`, designed to keep your fingers at the home row (hence the name).  The example given in their instructions is to map the <kbd>space</kbd> key to <kbd>shift</kbd>:  If the <kbd>space</kbd> key is used alone, it's a <kbd>space</kbd>; if used with another key, it's <kbd>shift</kbd>.  They also say that "Any pairs of keys are possible" for your use case with the <kbd>L</kbd> key doing double duty as <kbd>Control</kbd>.

Have a look here:

https://gitlab.com/at-home-modifier/at-home-modifier-evdev/wikis/home

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.